# What is the relationship between Pathfinder Society and Aspis Consortium?

Tags: golarion, factions

I am working on a self-written campaign that sticks tight to the original campaign setting of Golarion (including offical PFS Adventures).

Since my party are field agents of the Pathfinder Society and I want to introduce the Aspis Consortion to them, I would like to know what the relationship is between these two factions.

I have read the Inner Sea Guide and know that they work against each other since both are looking for artifacts and other stuff. But how far does this rivalry go? Do they kill each other? Are the leaders in contact and resolve conflicts with diplomacy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the Aspis and the Pathfinders are legal organizations in many countries. Therefore they can't just war on each other openly. And often their goals don't conflict in a given area. However, when they do, the competition can turn into hostilities...

1. In the Serpent's Skull Adventure Path, several groups organize safaris to find a lost city, including the Aspis and Pathfinders, and the competition wavers between friendly, frenemy, and enemy.
2. In Pathfinder Society, there are a variety of plotlines putting the two organizations at loggerheads, most notably the [Serpent's Rise plotline](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Serpent%27s_Rise) - there's [a long list of appearances of the Aspis](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Template:Aspis_Consortium_appearances) in PFS. There is much spying and murder, but again the murder needs to be kept on the down-low in law abiding realms.

There's no high level diplomacy I know of; the AC Patrons and the PFS Decemvirate are both secret leadership organizations, which makes that hard.